# How can I copy text in one screen window running vim and paste it to another without traditional copy and paste?

Tags: vim, display, copy-paste

I'd like to essentially yank text `y'k` and `mk` or `yy` in one instance of vim in one screen tab and paste it into another instance of vim in a different screen tab without having to select the text with my mouse and ctrl+c/ctrl+v.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just curious: why not use copy and paste?

Comment: Because in my `vimrc` file I have custom formatting turned on so when I do so, it'll screw with my indenting. Plus you can only copy and paste what's in the viewable portion of the window if you do that.

Comment: Does `:set paste` not help?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick oh wow mind blown. Never knew about that thx! But it still will only allow me to just copy what's on the viewable portion of the screen :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the register `*` (middle mouse paste) or `+` (“normal” clipboard):

```
"*y
"+y
```

**Edit:**

To make it more clear, the commands I wrote above assume that you marked some text visually. To copy the current line you can for example do: `V"*y` and then you can paste in every application with the middle mouse button. Or you can use `V"+y` and paste with `ctrl-v` or whatever shortcut you have configured to paste.

Comment: Hmm so I'm trying to get this to work, but it's just not? I'm typing in that sequence exactly. Is this supposed to be entered after I mark something? Forgive my ignorance on using those commands.

Comment: I think Marco means use `"*y'k` instead of `y'k` (then `"*p` instead of `p`)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick that seemed to work, but only when I was in the same vim instance (so it behaved just like what I was doing before, although I guess it just stored it in a register instead?) so when I switched to another vim instance, it didn't paste that from before.

Comment: Try `+` instead of `*`, as Marco suggests, that should use the system clipboard and therefore work across instances. The `*` would presumably work if you had multiple windows open in one instance of vim. I don't know if this is O/S dependent.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Marco wrote, you can add the following to your vimrc to use the `"*` or `"+` register in parallel with the unnamed register so that, for example, text yanked with `yy` will automatically go to the `"*` or `"+` register.

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
```

or

```
set clipboard^=unnamedplus
```

See

```
:help 'clipboard'
```